Frequencies from PitchTap Unreliable for Piano Scales
First off, thanks to everyone contributing to AudioKit- it's excellent. I'm building a Swift app using Audio Kit 5 that uses the device's microphone(iPad, iPhone etc) to listen to a student playing piano scales on an acoustic piano. The app uses the PitchTap to get real-time pitch and amplitude from the microphone.
For a C Major scale the student needs to play 4 octaves starting at C3 which is 130Hz. They then play each note of the scale till they get to C7 which is 1046 Hz. The student can play the scale at various tempos. Using a typical tempo, they would strike the next note's key about 2 or 3 times per second.
The student plays the scale without the piano's sustain pedal so each note is separated from the last. However, the acoustics of a piano are complex - e.g. a string hit for a note will also generate various harmonics.
Problem: PitchTap returns accurate and reliable pitches up until around pitch 880Hz but then starts to report pitches other than the pitch of the note played and/or does not report the pitch of the note played. PitchTap is set on the node AudioEngine().input (microphone) with a buffer size of 4096.
Questions:

What settings or techniques could I tweak to improve the accuracy of PitchTap at these higher frequencies? I've tried tweaking the PitchTap bufferSize and using an amplitude filter to ignore pitches from PitchTap with low amplitudes but so far not much improvement.

Should I consider using FFTTap instead of PitchTap or alongside PitchTap? I've thus far chosen to use PitchTap rather than FFTTap since I do not have the more in-depth knowledge of waveform processing I assume I'd need to be working the FFT raw data.

The pitch analysis has to be conducted in real time - is there any treatment I should apply to the microphone input before it is sampled by PitchTap? e.g. I only need to see the pitches generated by the notes on the piano keyboard.

Piano keys higher than pitch 880Hz dont use a damper pedal to silence the previous note so that previous note will still be sounding as the new note is struck. Quite likely this is one cause of the problem. Any tips on handling this type of pitch overlap using PitchTap


Thanks in advance for any help...

Try it against a flute or a piccolo at frequencies above 1kHz to see if the problem is instrument or frequency related. An FFT based method should become more accurate at higher frequencies within reason until you get up to around 10kHz or more. There are general audio spectrum analyser apps around which will show a waterfall diagram of frequency intensity vs time which might be enlightening.

the “waterfall diagram” is also included in main branch of AudioKitUI and called SpectrogramFlatView. this might help to find/see and then filter out overtones.

Thanks both Martin and Mahal. The waterfall diagram was very helpful. I'm getting pretty reliable pitch detection now for 3 piano octaves spanning from Middle C and up.
